# foreach no aparece en Vista

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net

intento que esto funcione pero no me muestra ningun error ni excepcion actualmente solo no aparece en la vista...

```
@if (Model.Recetas != null)
{
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (Receta receta in Model.Recetas)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>@Html.ActionLink(receta.Titulo, "Receta", new { id = receta.Id, @class = "Recetas" })</h4>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Receta", new { id = receta.Id })">
                        <img src="~/img/fotos/@receta.CoverImageFileName" alt="@receta.MostrarTexto" class="img-responsive" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Tenes un monton de preguntas sin respuestas aceptadas.Ninguno tuvo una respuesta valida? Esto parece ser el mismo problema que tenias mas temprano.. Lograste solucionar ese problema? tu model ahora si contiene algo?

Comment: Probaste utilizar un punto de interrupción en tu Controller antes de retornarlo para corroborar que tenga algún elemento en la colección de recetas?

Comment: mi ViewModel contiene esto: public Receta Receta { get; set; } public Slide Slide { get; set; } public List<Receta> Recetas { get; set; } solo esas tres lineas, lo de la nullreference ya no aparece pero tampoco aparecen mis recetas en la vista index

Comment: En la [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179973/como-acceder-a-un-private-static-array-desde-otra-clase) te he comentado este problema también. El tema es que no has inicialiazado nada en el modelo.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY es necesario que veas este workshop de ASP.net MVC 5. Saludos :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya te he comentado tras inicializar correctamente el Modelo esta parte de la vista quedaría así:

```
@if (Model.RepositorioRecetas != null)
    {
    <div class="row">
            @foreach (Receta receta in Model.RepositorioRecetas.GetRecetas())
            {
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <h4>@Html.ActionLink(receta.Titulo, "Receta", new { id = receta.Id, @class = "Recetas" })</h4>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Receta", new {id = receta.Id})">
                            <img src="~/img/fotos/@receta.CoverImageFileName" alt="@receta.MostrarTexto" class="img-responsive" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Me funciono!! mil gracias estoy feliz, ademas ahora entiendo mejor como funciona muchas gracias!! :D como te doy puntos? @ElGerar

Comment: Si te ha funcionado marca la respuesta como válida. Así puede que ayude a alguien más. Un saludo

Comment: solo hago click en el check no? o debo hacer algo mas? gracias :)