# ¿como acceder a un private static array desde otra clase?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
private static List<Receta> _recetas = new List<Receta>
{
    //contenido array
}; 
public List<Receta> GetRecetas()
{
    return _recetas;
}
```

Este es el código si tengo un metodo Get pero ¿como accedo desde otra clase sin pasar null?, disculpen por preguntar tanto, de verdad llevo días intentando hacer lo de dos modelos en una vista...

El código completo se encuentra en [GitHub](https://github.com/PequeCeci/Guava)

Comment: Este articulo te puede ayudar: [How to get the value of a private static field from a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628666/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-private-static-field-from-a-class) Espero te sirva!

Comment: no entiendo tu problema : con el metodo GetRecetas() accedes a la lista _recetas pues este metodo te regresara la lista en cuestion. o quieres acceder a la lista como una propiedad ? ... ya vi tu codigo.. lo tienes todo mal....

Comment: solo quiero que me devuelva _recetas pero me devuelve null, voy a proceder a leer el articulo, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no tengo ni idea de lo que estas tratando de hacer te mando un minicódigo que accede a una lista privada estática:

```
public class Receta{
    public string ingrediente;
}

public class libro{
    private static List<Receta> _recetas = new List<Receta>();
    public List<Receta> GetRecetas(){
        return _recetas;
    }
}
```

Lo que no entiendo es como tratas de hacer que el método `public list<recetas> getrecetas()` este adentro de `_recetas`... eso no se puede....

Ahora imaginemos que este es tu `main`:

```
libro libroRecetas = new libro();
libroRecetas.GetRecetas().Add(new Receta { ingrediente="tocino" });
Console.WriteLine(libroRecetas.GetRecetas()[0].ingrediente);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Trata de ver que es lo que estas haciendo mal, obvio si tu lista esta vacía no te enviara ningún resultado.

Comment: uso add y vuelvo a agregar todas las propiedades de mi clase? :/  estaria repitiendo codigo XD

Comment: oye se que es muy atrevido de mi parte pero aqui dejo el link a github de lo que estoy intentando hacer, si tienes tiempo hechale una mirada por favor https://github.com/PequeCeci/Guava.git soy solo principiante

Answer (score 1):

Bueno le acabo de echar un ojo a tu repositorio y como poco veo dos errores que no te permiten cargar la pagina correctamente. Desde luego debes darle otra vuelta a lo que es el patrón MVC pero esto te permitirá al menos ejecutarla:

Por un lado en tu clase `HomeController` :

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //var viewModel = Modelo.RepositorioRecetas.GetRecetas(); Código antiguo
        var viewModel = new Modelos();

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Por otro lado, en la clase `Modelos` añade un constructor que inicialice lo necesario, por ejemplo:

```
 public Modelos()
    {
        RepositorioRecetas = new RepositorioRecetas();
    }
```

Si luego en la pagina principal en el cuerpo del `Index.cshtml` haces el siguiente cambio:

```
    @if (Model.RepositorioRecetas != null)
        {
        <div class="row">
            @* Linea que tenias anteriormente y he comentado *@
            @*@foreach (Receta receta in Model.RepositorioRecetas)*@ 
                @foreach (Receta receta in Model.RepositorioRecetas.GetRecetas())
                {
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="well">
                            <h4>@Html.ActionLink(receta.Titulo, "Receta", new { id = receta.Id, @class = "Recetas" })</h4>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Receta", new {id = receta.Id})">
                                <img src="~/img/fotos/@receta.CoverImageFileName" alt="@receta.MostrarTexto" class="img-responsive" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
        </div>
    }
```

Con esto ya te carga por lo menos la pagina principal. 
Mucho animo y paciencia

Comment: listo, ahora podemos cerrar la pregunta xD